# An inequality involving the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

I’m looking at a set of [notes](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/lll.pdf) on the LLL algorithm, where we have the following setup: let $b_1,\dots,b_n\in\mathbb Z^n$ be a set of $\mathbb R$-linearly independent vectors, and let $\tilde b_1,\dots,\tilde b_n$ be the Gram-Schmidt orhogonalizations of the $b_i$. At one point in one of the proofs (the very end of the proof of Claim 2, in the middle of page 7), it is claimed that for any $j$,
$$
|\tilde b_j| \geq \left( |\tilde b_1|^2|\tilde b_2|^2\dots|\tilde b_j|^2\right)^{-1}.
$$

Apparently this is obvious, but I’m not quite seeing it. (Well, I can see it for $j=1$ since $\tilde b_1=b_1$ is an integer vector, but I don’t quite see how to extend this to higher $j$.) Does anyone have a proof or a reference for this inequality?

Comment: In the notes you are reading, it is written that $D^2_{B,i}\tilde{b_i}$ is an integer vector. Are you ok with this statement ? Any non-zero integer vector has norm $\geq 1$. This seems to give the desired inequality.

Comment: Ah. That would do it—thanks for pointing this out. I probably should not have missed that…